# What's the word for "urge to go to the toilet"?

Tags: word-request

I am pretty sure there's a word for it, but I forgot what the word was completely. By "urge to go to the toilet", I mean the desire to go peeing or pooping obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the phrase "**caught short**". In the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be_caught_short) is

> **be caught short**
>   PHRASE
>
> **1.1** *British informal* Urgently need to urinate or defecate.
>   *those caught short in the store will have to pay £1 to use the toilets*

Comment: This is a colloquialism.  In the US, no one would know what you mean.  Also, I would be careful assuming it's a *common* expression in the UK, as I've never heard it used in any British television programs.

Comment: @Andrew I don't *assume* it's a common expression in the UK, I know it, which is why I wrote this answer. Pretty much everyone here would understand what is meant. The dictionary reference says "British informal" so you should challenge *them* with your TV survey.

Comment: I think yours is a good answer, but problematic as the *accepted* answer.  There are perhaps several hundred colloquial ways to say "need to urinate/defecate", many of which would not be understood outside the local dialect, and so of limited use to an English learner.  It's better to teach the one that can be used *anywhere*, and then add in some regional variations.

Comment: Moreover "caught short" is in general use to mean *"failing to reach some intended goal"*, which might cause confusion if an English learner reads something like:  *"The Australian was **caught short** of the crease by Ambati Rayudu's direct throw"*  as it's odd for a sports announcer to suggest one of the players needs to pee.

Comment: @Andrew I didn't accept my own answer! On the other hand the American euphemism "need to go to the bathroom" may be widely misunderstood too, a bathroom being where one takes a bath, not a pee. Heck, many of us didn't even *have* a bathroom until the 1960/70s.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single word for this.  The actual expression varies between English dialects, but in the US it's common to say something like:

> I need to go the bathroom.

If (for whatever reason) you want to be more descriptive, you can say something like

> I have a full bladder.

Naturally, there are dozens or perhaps hundreds of slang expressions for this, most of them fairly crude.